# Spring Data REST: Infer owner from authenticated request

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have an `@Entity` that has a field `owner`:

```java
@Entity
@EntityListeners({TalkListener.class})
public class Talk {
    private @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, optional = false) User owner;
    // ...
}
```

Note: I have a listener in place that implementes `@PrePersist`. From what I have read it is discouraged to lookup request parameters from there (maybe it is also impossible, I didn't go on researching in this direction). There is the [section about events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events) in the docs, but it also seems purely entity-related and not taking the context of the request into account.

I would like to infer the owner from the authenticated user that `POST`s the request. What is the easiest way to do so? If it is necessary to override the `POST` a snippet or linked example would be much appreciated.

**Update 1**:
@NeilMcGuigan suggested using Spring Data JPA's [auditing features](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#auditing), which include a `@CreatedBy` annotation that would clearly solve the original question (and I would accept it as an answer).

**Update 2**:
A good tutorial about auditing with Spring Data JPA as well as an alternative of getting the principal within entity lifecycle events can be found [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-auditing-part-two/).

---

For educational purpose, what would be another way if I needed to access some value from the request to populate a value in my entity (say my current use case wasn't `@CreatedBy` but something different)?

Comment: Use Spring Data JPA auditing feature?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Thanks, that is good to know and would definitely solve the presented use case. For educational purpose, what would be another way if I needed to access some value from the request to populate a value in my entity? (say my current use case wasn't `@CreatedBy` but something different).